# Convergence of a convergence series with $e^{in}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-sum

I am facing difficulties with this question:
It says show by using the comparison test that the folowing complex series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Re(e^{in\phi})}{2^n}$$

The $\Re $ refers to the real part of the complex number.
Thank you for your help, I don't know where to start from.

Comment: **Hint:** $|\Re e^{in \phi}|\leq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$ |\Re (e^{in\phi})| = |\cos(n\phi)| \le 1 
$$
Hence
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac{\Re (e^{in\phi})}{2^n}\right|
  &\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\\
  &= 1 < \infty
\end{align*}